# mysql query to fetch unique data by status and expiry date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table:

```
uid sr  status      expirydate
abc 111 inactive    jan'17
def 111 inactive    feb'17
ghi 111 active      jul'17
jkl 222 inactive    jun'17
mno 222 inactive    mar'17
pqr 333 active      jul'17
stu 333 active      dec'17
vwx 333 inactive    may'17
yzz 333 inactive    feb'17
```

I want mysql query so that I can get data of uid ghi who is last active uid and has expiry date of current month (jul'17).

How can I get this data with a mysql query.

Thanks

Comment: "I can get data of uid ghi who is last active".  You have only one row with a uid of "ghi".  I don't understand the rest of the conditions.

Comment: Want all single records with current month expiry date but there should not be any other active uid. For example, dont want uid pqr because uid stu is still active and his expiry date is dec'17.

Hope I'm able to make you understand what I exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't a simple `where` clause do what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.expirydate = '201701' and  -- or however you really express the month
      status = 'active';
```

Comment: This will give result of ghi and pqr. Dont want pqr because there's still one more uid stu still active and his expiry date is dec'17.

Comment: select *, count(sr) as sr from csvtbl where status='active' group by uid having sr = 1

This query gives following result of all ghi, pqr & stu. Want only ghi in result. If occurrence of 'active' is more than 1 then don't want that record.